# C++ inheritance class virtual functions

Tags: c++, function, class, inheritance, virtual

I have a base class and a derived class, I am trying to implement a virtual load function to add an extra member engineSize to the SportCar class, it should load the basic car details included in the Car class i.e CarName, Colour etc but also include engineSize which is unique to the SportsCar class. But it does not seem to workout well. Below I have included my code. Currently, it just defaults to the details included in the default constructor i.e. "Unknown".

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

 class Car
{
 public:
   Car();
   virtual void Load(ifstream& carFile);
   int LoadString(string filename);

protected:
  string CarName;
  int Age;
  string Colour;
  double Price;
  int countUsers;
  Car *ptrToCarList;
};

class SportsCar : public Car
{
public: 
  SportsCar();
  virtual void LoadSports(ifstream& carFile);
  int LoadString(string filename);
  void display();
protected:
  int engineSize;
  SportsCar *ptrToSportsCarList;
  int countUsers;

};

Car::Car()
{
  CarName = "Unknown";
  countUsers = 2;
}

void Car::Load(ifstream& carFile)
{
  carFile >> CarName >> Age >> Colour >> Price;
}

int Car::LoadString(string filename)
{
  ifstream inFile(filename);

  if (!inFile)
  {
    cout << "Sorry, file not found" << endl;
    return -1;
  }

ptrToCarList = new Car[countUsers];

for (int i = 0; i < countUsers; i++)
{
    ptrToCarList[i].Load(inFile);
}
inFile.close();
return 0;
}

void SportsCar::display()
{
  cout << CarName << " " << Age << " " << Colour << " " << Price << " " <<engineSize <<endl;

}


void SportsCar::LoadSports(ifstream& carFile)
{
  Car::Load(carFile);
  carFile >> engineSize;
}

SportsCar::SportsCar() :Car()
{


}


int SportsCar::LoadString(string filename)
{
  ifstream inFile(filename);

if (!inFile)
{
    cout << "Sorry, file not found" << endl;
    return -1;
}

ptrToSportsCarList = new SportsCar[countUsers];

for (int i = 0; i < countUsers; i++)
{
    ptrToSportsCarList[i].LoadSports(inFile);
}
inFile.close();
return 0;
}

int main()
{
  SportsCar example2;
  example2.LoadString("sportsCarFile.txt");
  example2.display();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you really need same variable countUsers in SportsCar? SportsCar::LoadString function use countUsers that is not initialized. You are initializing countUsers but from Car class

Comment: Based on what you've done, what do you think `example2.LoadString("sportsCarFile.txt");` does? I mean, what does the code do, not what you want it to do.

Comment: Your base class `Car` should have a virtual destructor.

Comment: Why does one car contain both the information for a car *and* a collection of cars? My car is completely unaware of other cars.

Comment: `LoadString` should also be virtual.

Comment: and what does the file look like ?

Comment: btw this question shows you have not learnt anything from your previous question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29593822/c-base-class-load-function

Comment: I am still not sure, I am new to programming. You can't be a expert overnight.@Philip Stuyck

Answer (score 0):

If you want hold many cars in cars that mean that is somethings wrong with that design.

1. Consider making class Garage ;)
2. `example2.LoadString("sportsCarFile.txt");` doesn't call `LoadSports` as you expect because countUsers is 0. Because in derived class you have declaration that is hiding initialization from contructor of Car.
3. You have `ptrToSportsCarList` and `ptrToCarList`. You probably want only `ptrToCarList` to hold cars because of polymorphism you can use on LoadSports function
4. Consider moving LoadSports to Base class and rename it to be more generic, and make it virtual so could be called from `ptrToCarList`, not from `ptrToSportsCarList` as mentioned in pt. 2.

Comment: Thanks for your response, how would I display one car only in the car class if I have a Garage class to deal with the loading and sorting of all the cars. @userbb